# Comparison between signed and unsigned integer expression for loop error

Tags: c++, string

I was writing a program that went through a string but in the for loop it gave me an error and the answers online that I found used only vectors.

```
std::string str = "Test";
for (int i = 0, max = str.size; i < max; i++)
```

Comment: "it gave me an error" - but you didn't think it would be relevant to our attempts to help you, to actually *quote that error*? Why not? *Always*, *always* include any error messages you get in your question - *verbatim*.

Comment: Did you not read the question title? _Always, always_ read the title of the question

Comment: Yes, I did read the question title. But I didn't find a verbatim quote of the error message you got from your compiler.

Comment: "Comparison between signed and unsigned integer expression [-Wsign-compare]" is the actual warning message from the compiler. I left out the last two words because it is not as important and also the people that responded already knew how to deal with the problem so my title did complete its purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::string::size` is a member function, you need to call it:

```
for (int i = 0, max = str.size(); i < max; i++)
//                            ^^ here
```

... and in order to make the issue with signed-unsigned conversion go away:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0, max = str.size(); i < max; i++)
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^ index type for standard library container
```

Besides, if you need to process every `char`  in the string, consider using a range based for loop;

```
for (char c : str)
   // ...
```

Comment: Technically the member field `size_type` is the type for indexing/sizes. Which usually is std::size_t, but not necessarily.

Comment: @Neijwiert That's true, but you know... `for (std::string::size_type i = ...` while knowing that it's nothing but `std::size_t`?! It's the same type across all standard library implementations for years...

Comment: Despite adding std::size_t the warning still persists
Edit: Nevermind I built the wrong file

Comment: Can you paste the warning? Are you sure it's emitted for the `for` loop in that form?

Comment: @lubgr I'm aware of that, that's why I said 'technically', since you explicitly put comments for the `std::size_t`. Not saying that your answer is wrong or something.